# Convert string to valid url path segment

Tags: typescript, url, path

I want to generate valid url path segments from a names (countries, regions, location names) in different languages. As output I would like to have only '[a-z]' and '-'. Is there any library that do that for me?
I see especially special letter like 'ä', 'á' and so on as problem.

Is there anything that could help me with that?

Comment: In which programming language? You tagged java and typescript.

Comment: Yes, but the language is not so important. TS/JS in favor.

Comment: “As output I would like to have only '[a-z]' and '-'.”  Removing such characters entirely probably is not a good solution.  URLs encode non-ASCII characters as escaped UTF-8 octets.  `ä` would appear in a URL as `%c3%a4`.  Any good URI construction library will do this automatically.

Answer (score 0):

For JS you could use: `npm i diacritics`.

Comment: modern-diacritics looks a bit more suitable for my task. But thanks for the hint!